# Story about a pair of twins - secret passage leads to different world, find missing dad, everything different

Tags: story-identification

I read this book many years ago but quite can't remember it. The main kids are twins. The boy needs glasses and is allergic to like everything and the girl is perfectly normal. They go to visit a relative and find a secret passage that leads to a different world where everything is different. The boy no longer needs glasses but the girl suddenly does. They find out that their missing dad is in this world.
I really don't know anymore but if you know it, please tell me!

Comment: Can you give us an approximate time frame when you read it? 5 years ago? 10? 50? Was this in English? Did you read it in North America? Was this a novel-length book? A kids book?

Answer (score 3):

This is probably *The Ever Breath*, by Julianna Baggott.
It fits in all particulars.

To quote the *School Library Journal*:

> Baggott, who also writes under the name N.E. Bode, introduces twins Camille and Truman. She exudes health while he suffers from every imaginable allergy.

Camille needs Truman's glasses.

> "You're wearing my glasses!" Truman said.

And, of course, Truman has many allergies.

> "I think I'm going to throw up," Truman said. "I have a lot of allergies and a strong gag reflex."

Reviews also mention a secret passageway and the twins' father.

I would guess that "many years ago" can't be more than 7, since the book was published in 2009.